# How do I ensure "since" takes the meaning I want?

Tags: meaning

I have a sentence like this:

> Since I graduated, I have been working for xyz in abc.

**Since can mean:**

1. in the intervening period between (the time mentioned) and the time under consideration, typically the present.
2. for the reason that: because.

---

As both fit, the sentence is a little ambiguous in my opinion.
I want it to mean the first (time duration). How do I make sure it does that?

"*Since the time I...*" sounds valid to me, but is there a better way to put it?

Comment: _Since my graduation . . ._

Comment: @BarrieEngland I really like how that sounds. Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Presumably this is going on some résumé/CV or application, where context will make it quite clear that it's a time period.

Comment: Also, as far as time period goes, it must be through the present, not just any "time under consideration."

Comment: _Since graduating . . ._

Comment: Another option is to add ‘ever’ before it: “Ever since I graduated …”. That is not necessarily a very good option from a stylistic point of view, though, depending on how long it has been since your graduation, and how much you like your job. ;-)

Comment: The sentence is not going to be ambiguous when used in context. Examining an isolated sentence is contrary to how the English language works.

Answer (score 1):

Try "I have been working for XYZ in abc since I graduated/ since my graduation"