# How to distinguish the temporal and causal meanings of 'since'

Tags: etymology, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

[Here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/134122/how-to-use-since-to-imply-from-the-time-that-not-because-of-can-tense-it) is a question by [Cardinal](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/21666/cardinal) from ELL (reproduced below).  Although it [already has an answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/134150/50615), I am looking for **more detail**, specifically about the **differences in the causal and temporal meanings of 'since'**, and **how they came about**.

**The definitions for since are:**

> 1. In the intervening period between (the time mentioned) and the time under consideration, typically the present.
> 2. For the reason that; because.

Note the difference in 'a period of time' and 'because'.

**Question:**

- **How did these two meanings develop?**

---

Related question: [How do I ensure "since" takes the meaning I want?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/139627/how-do-i-ensure-since-takes-the-meaning-i-want), which doesn't cover etymology, rather avoiding confusion.

If you would like to discuss this, there is a [meta post](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10437/re-ask-for-more-detail-in-elu-than-ell).

Comment: The conflation of ‘since [a point in time]’ and ‘since [a reason is the case]’ is not at all limited to English. It is, in fact, a very common cross-linguistic phenomenon to use a word that refers to a point later in time than another as the basis of a word that refers to the result of a reason. Irish _ó_ and Japanese から _-kara_ also mean both ‘since’ and ‘because’ (and ‘from’); French _depuis_ (time) and _puisque_ (reason) are both based on _puis_ (from a Vulgar Latin comparative of _post_, i.e., ‘later’); Greek _αφού_ (reason) is from _ἀπὸ οὗ_ ‘from that’; etc. So why? Because language.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61630/discussion-on-question-by-marcellothearcane-how-to-distinguish-the-temporal-and).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I ensure "since" takes the meaning I want?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/139627/how-do-i-ensure-since-takes-the-meaning-i-want)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP says, "I am looking for more detail, specifically about the differences in the causal and temporal meanings of 'since', and how they came about," or how the two meanings of *since* developed.

First, in brief, *since* has been around a long time, in both senses. The OED includes definitions and quotations relating to each from Middle English *sithen*, an adverb, preposition, and conjunction:

> Forms:  α. OE sioððan, OE–ME siððan, ME siððon, ME siððen; OE siðþan,
>   siþþan, siþþon, ME siþþen (ME Orm. siþþenn), ME siþthen, ME sythethyn,
>   sitthen; ME siðen (ME siden, syden), ME siþen (ME siþan), ME syþen, ME
>   siþin; ME–16, 18 sithen (ME sithenne, sithin, sithyn, sithun, 16
>   sithene); ME–15 sythen (ME sythene, sythin, sythinne, sythyn, sython,
>   sythun). β. OE–ME seoððan, ME seoð-, seodþen ( soððen); OE seoþðan, ME
>   seod-, ME seoðþan; OE seoþþan, ME seoþþen (ME soþþen); ME seððan, ME
>   seððen (ME sed-), ME seþþen; OE seoðan, ME seoðen, seoþen; ME seðen,
>   ME seiþin, ME seþen, seþin; ME–15 sethen (ME sethenne), ME sethyn,
>   ME–15 sethin (ME sethinne, sethun). γ. OE syð-, ME sydþan, OE–ME
>   syþðan, syððan (ME syððon), ME suððen (ME suden), ME swo-, swu-,
>   souððen; OE syþþan ( syþan), ME suþþen, sut(t)hen.
>
> Etymology: Old English siþþon, siþþan, etc. (see above), for earlier
>   *síð þon (þan) ‘subsequent to that’ (compare æfter þon, and German seitdem), 
>   with shortening of the first vowel. The Middle English
>   siþen, sithen, however, may also represent Old Norse síðan (Danish
>   siden), of the same meaning.(Show Less) Obs.

There are far more definitions relating to time than to causality.

Under *sithens* the OED lists one definition as a conjunction:

> 2a. **Seeing that**; = sith adv. 2. Now arch.Very common from c1550 to
>   c1650.
>
> 1377   Langland Piers Plowman B. xix. 15   Why calle ȝe hym
>   cryst,..sithenes iuwes calle hym ihesus?
>
> 1898   E. W. Hamilton Mawkin of Flow xiii   It's our plain duty to
>   bide by it, sithens we was sent by Buccleuch to be guided by the
>   hound.

One definition of *since* from the OED is:

> II 4a. Because that; seeing that; inasmuch as. 1577   B. Googe tr. C.
>   Heresbach Foure Bks. Husbandry i. f. 7v   Sins it is not yet dinner
>   tyme, let vs walke about.

Turning to time, one OED definition (under B, preposition) is:

> Definitions under B (preposition) include:
>
> 1. Ever or continuously from (a specified time, etc.) till now.
>
> 1734 tr. C. Rollin Anc. Hist. I. 255 It was now five months and a half
>   since his first setting out.
>
> 1780 Mirror No. 103 I inherited a law-suit, kept alive by various
>   means, ever since the year thirty~three.
>
> 1861 Thackeray Four Georges iv. 168 He sleeps since thirty years.

This last--"he sleeps since thirty years"--would be an error today, and is the mistake most common among English language learners.

Native English speakers do not have a problem figuring out which meaning of *since* is meant, and @Clare's point that only sentences in isolation are likely to be confused is one with which I agree.  But it's possible to write sentences likely to be confusing to readers, who have to backtrack to figure out what is meant.  The solution is to recast (rewrite) a sentence that can be misunderstood.

That said, the best discussion of *since* I've found is from English Grammar Today:[since](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/linking-words-and-expressions/since)

> We use since as a preposition, a conjunction and an adverb to refer to
>   a time, and as a conjunction to introduce a reason.   Since: time We
>   use since to refer back to a previous point in time. We use since as a
>   preposition with a date, a time or a noun phrase: It was the band’s
>   first live performance since May 1990. (since + date) I have been
>   happily married for 26 years, since the age of 21. (since + noun
>   phrase) We also use since as a conjunction to introduce a subordinate
>   clause: It’s so long since I saw them. (since + clause) Lenny had
>   slept most of the way since leaving Texas. (since + clause) He’s been
>   back to the office a few times since he retired. (since + clause)
>   Since and tenses
>
> When since introduces an action or event at a point of time in the
>   past, we can use the past simple or present perfect after since and
>   the present perfect in the main clause:
>
> They haven’t received any junk mail since they moved house.
>
> They haven’t received any junk mail since they’ve moved house.
>
> We can use the past simple, present perfect or past perfect after
>   since with the expression it + be + time + since:
>
> It’s been years since I rode a bike. (it’s = it has)
>
> It’s been years since I’ve ridden a bike. (it’s = it has)
>
> It’s years since I rode a bike. (it’s = it is)
>
> It’s years since I’ve ridden a bike. (it’s = it is)
>
> It’d been years since I’d ridden a bike. (it’d = it had)
>
> It’s been years since … is more common in American English than It’s
>   years since …. When since introduces a state in the past that is still
>   continuing in the present, we use a present perfect form of the verb
>   after since and a present perfect form of the verb in the main clause:
>
> Since I’ve been back at work, I’ve been feeling great.
>
> Since + -ing
>
> We can use since + -ing form to refer to time when the subject of the
>   verb is the same in the main clause and the subordinate clause:
>
> Since leaving school, he has had three or four temporary jobs. (Since
>   he left school, he has …)
>
> Since moving from a Chicago suburb to southern California a few months
>   ago, I’ve learned how to play a new game called Lanesmanship. (Since I
>   moved …, I’ve learned …)   Since, since then
>
> We can use since or since then as an adverb of time when the time
>   reference is understood from the context:
>
> His father doesn’t talk to him. They had an argument a couple of years
>   ago and they haven’t spoken since. (since they had the argument)
>
> They bought the house in 2006 and they’ve done a lot of work on it
>   since then. (since 2006)
>
> We use ever since as a stronger form of since or since then:
>
> When I was young, I had a little collie dog, but one day he bit me
>   really badly. I’ve hated dogs ever since.   Since: reason
>
> We use since as a subordinating conjunction to introduce a subordinate
>   clause. We use it to give a reason for something:
>
> Sean had no reason to take a taxi since his flat was near enough to
>   walk to.
>
> Since her husband hated holidays so much, she decided to go on her
>   own.
>
> They couldn’t deliver the parcel since no one was there to answer the
>   door.
>
> Since: typical errors
>
> • We don’t use since with extended periods of time. We use for:
>
> She was waiting for four hours.
>
> Not: She was waiting since four hours.
>
> • We use since, not from, with a clause referring back to a point in
>   time:
>
> I’ve been swimming since I was three years old.
>
> I’ve been swimming from the age of three.
>
> Not: I’ve been swimming from I was three years old.
>
> • We use since, not once, to introduce a reason:
>
> I think I should have my money back since I didn’t have what was
>   promised in the brochure.
>
> Not: I think I should have my money back once I didn’t have …
>
> • We use since, not ago, after ‘it’s a long time’ when we refer back
>   to a point in time:
>
> It’s a long time since your last letter.
>
> Not: It’s a long time ago your last letter.

In summary, the evidence suggests that the two main senses of *since* developed concurrently, and it's a word easy for non-native speakers to misuse.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note on the present perfect in *since*-clauses.

The present perfect establishes a *terminus ad quem*.  It looks back over its shoulder at the past, so to speak, and says: as of this moment such-and-such state obtains:

> I have eaten seal-meat.

**The present perfect does not establish a *terminus post quem*.**

> Ever since I have eaten seal meat ... <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

We would say rather *Ever since I **ate** seal-meat...* to establish a point-in-time to serve as a *terminus post quem*.

> (Ever) Since I *have seen* his first film, I have been following that director.  <sup>ungrammatical as temporal</sup>
>
> (Ever) Since I *saw* his first film, I have been following that director.

So, when you see the present perfect in the *since*-clause, **since** will be causative, not temporal:

> Since I have eaten seal-meat, I know what it tastes like.
>
> (Ever) Since I *have eaten* seal-meat I have known what it tastes like. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

Comment: -1 because *(Ever)  since I've moved to Boston I've been a Patriots fan*: these kind of sentences are grammatical.

Comment: @Clare.We disagree on this. Can you cite some attestations? Would you say "Ever since I have seen the Empire State Building, I've wanted to move to New York?"
  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ever+since+I+moved%2Cever+since+I+have+moved&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cever%20since%20I%20moved%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score -1):

Confusion about whether 'since' has been used in a causal or a temporal sense can arise only when the tenses are in agreement so that a temporal meaning can be grammatically assumed:

> He has been moody since he lost his job.
>
> She has tried to improve her English since she joined ELU.

There is no ambiguity when sentences are constructed to avoid this arrangement; then 'since' can only be causal, as in the following example;

> He is moody, since he has lost his job.
>
> She wants to improve her English, since she is going to join ELU.

If the sentence structure is to be retained then I would certainly advise a Learner to substitute 'because' for 'since', to remove ambiguity.

> He has been moody because he lost his job.
>
> She has been trying to improve her English, because she has joined ELU.

---

Note: this answer specifically addresses the first question originally raised by OP:

> How can one avoid such confusion/ambiguity in the use of 'since' (I paraphrase, because OP has now removed this question.)

Note 2: OP has *since* edited to focus solely on this (originally second) question:

> How did these two meanings develop?

This happened *since* I prepared this answer (but before I could post it) -- however I am not changing my answer *since* I have no answer to OP's revised question, *because* I am neither an etymologist nor a linguist.

Comment: What about the etymology of *why* 'since' has these constructions?

Comment: As I stated in note 2, I know nothing about that 'why', (because I am neither an etymologist nor a linguist) but I am sure somebody at ELU can tell you why, because we have many genuine experts here!

Comment: In which case, this is a perfect answer to the question everyone thinks this is a duplicate of :)

Comment: It *was* a duplicate with a 'why' added; then it became a question of 'why' alone, and that might save it from being closed as duplicate. It is a good question because we don't think 'why' about these grammar things as often as we should, so this is the type of thinking we need more of at EL and U.

Comment: But speakers, even basic speakers of English, don't need to construct sentences so as to avoid any possible ambiguity. Sentences are spoken in context, from which the meaning is known. Only sentences in isolation, examined as if they were laboratory rats, have this ambiguity.

Comment: @Clare OP specifically asked 'how can we avoid such confusion/ambiguity in the use of 'since'?' Which is what I was answering, although this question was later edited out by OP. Whether there is any real need to avoid ambiguity is an equally relevant but very different question.

Comment: No, my comment is a direct answer: you avoid ambiguity by using the sentence in an actual communicative context and not by examining it in isolation.

Comment: @Clare thanks for the clarification, which makes excellent sense. I would aso advice any Learner never to interpret a sentence in isolation, out of context.

Comment: @English Student I concur. Your program, however, means in effect forbidding the Learner to answer most questions on exams; and although I am of the firm opinion that most exam questions should not be asked, much less answered, the Learner may not enjoy the resulting marks.

Comment: @Stoney B the Learner can be allowed to interpret sentences in isolation for answering examination questions, possibly as a 'special exception' where the *context* is not proper/actual usage, but often what is taught in class and what answer is 'taught to be correct' -- provided that the parties teaching all of that *are also* setting the examination questions! Not only a Learner but any one of us should struggle with numerous such exam questions where the 'expected answer' has not only not been taught us, but also does not reflect actual usage. When the context is exams, the examiner is King!