# Is "since" ambiguous in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

Is "since" ambiguous?

Cambridge Dictionary - Since: from a particular time in the past until a later time, or until now

However, whenever I hear: "I haven't done x since y." I interpret it as the last time they did "x" was "y".

However, by the dictionary, it means 'from y on, I haven't done x." (The last time I did "x" was before "y".

Is there a reason why?

What if you say: "I haven't done x since y on." Does this make sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/396833/how-to-distinguish-the-temporal-and-causal-meanings-of-since

Comment: The meaning can be ambiguous.  Likely the only word in English that can cause this problem.